# Is 「っしょ」possibly a colloquial sentence ending particle?

Tags: usage, particles, slang

In this chapter of Chainsawman I saw this 「いいっしょ」 and am confused by what it means.

[image: いいっしょ]

Are there any other particles like this? I don't see this on any lists online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the manga, but this is likely a colloquial way of saying 「いいでしょう！」or 「いいよね！」.

Please visit [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200923090455/https://japanesedialects.com/hokkaido-tohoku/hokkaido-dialect/issho/) for a little more background (assuming characters are speaking one of the northern dialects).

Keep in mind, this is not a particle and not necessarily always sentence-ending either.

Comment: Would something like this be common in Japan? Like, is it so common that generally anyone with a different dialect would understand, or is it something the common Japanese individual wouldn't know at first?

Comment: From my experience it would be pretty universally understood, but I'll leave it for natives and other pseudo-speakers like myself to lend their voices.